# Token '==' is unexpected ngClass

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

hello i am trying to use several expression in my `ng-class` directive but i keep getting this error in my browser console:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '==' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 13 of the expression [{ isWorking == true }] starting at [== true }].
```

This is my code:

```
ng-class="{ 'btn-danger': isReady == true || isError == true, 'btn-warning': isWorking == true, 'btn-success': isSuccess == true }"
```

Could someone please tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: try dropping the `== true` for the booleans

Comment: you just need brackets like `(isReady == something) || (isError == something)`, imo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to explicitly check for `true`. Observe the following...

```
ng-class="{ 'btn-danger': isReady || isError, 'btn-warning': isWorking, 'btn-success': isSuccess }"
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/0yf6t6c7/) - simple demo

---

Also check out [The Many Ways To Use ngClass](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass) - this blog post is very helpful for doing anything with `ng-class`, I highly recommend giving it a look.